# Add calculated key to collection

Tags: f#, f#-data

Please consider this dataset, composed by man and woman, and that I filter in a second moment according to few variables:

```
type ls = JsonProvider<"...">
let dt = ls.GetSamples()

let dt2 = 
dt |> Seq.filter (fun c -> c.Sex = "male" && c.Height > Some 150)

dt2

[{"sex":"male","height":180,"weight":85},
{"sex":"male","height":160" "weight":60},
{"sex":"male","height":180,"weight":85}]
```

Lets suppose that I would like to add a fourth key "body mass index" or "bmi", and that its value is roughly given by "weight"/"height". Hence I expect:

```
[{"sex":"male","height":180,"weight":85, "bmi":(180/85)},
{"sex":"male","height":160" "weight":60, "bmi":(160/60},
{"sex":"male","height":180,"weight":85, "bmi":(180/85)}]
```

I thought that [map.Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/map.add%5B'key,'value%5D-method-%5Bfsharp%5D) may help.

```
let dt3 = dt2.Add("bmi", (dt2.Height/dt2.Weight))
```

Unfortunately, it returns an error:

```
error FS0039: The field, constructor or member 'Add' is not defined
```

I am sure there are further errors in my code, but without this function I cannot actually look for them. Am I, at least, approaching the problem correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating modified versions of the JSON is sadly one thing that the F# Data type provider does not make particularly easy. What makes that hard is the fact that we can infer the type from the source JSON, but we cannot "predict" what kind of fields people might want to add.

To do this, you'll need to access the underlying representation of the JSON value and operate on that. For example:

```
type ls = JsonProvider<"""
  [{"sex":"male","height":180,"weight":85},
   {"sex":"male","height":160,"weight":60},
   {"sex":"male","height":180,"weight":85}]""">

let dt = ls.GetSamples()

let newJson = 
  dt
  |> Array.map (fun recd ->
      // To do the calculation, you can access the fields via inferred types 
      let bmi = float recd.Height / float recd.Weight

      // But now we need to look at the underlying value, check that it is
      // a record and extract the properties, which is an array of key-value pairs
      match recd.JsonValue with
      | JsonValue.Record props ->
          // Append the new property to the existing properties & re-create record
          Array.append [| "bmi", JsonValue.Float bmi |] props
          |> JsonValue.Record
      | _ -> failwith "Unexpected format" )

// Re-create a new JSON array and format it as JSON
JsonValue.Array(newJson).ToString()
```

Comment: Actually, I am really having a hard time with it. Anyway, it works perfectly, thanks. I am studing it carefully. I have only one question.  Previuosly, I filtered the dataset with `let dt2 = 
dt |> Seq.filter (fun c -> c.Sex = "male" && c.Height > Some 150)`. This makes of `dt2` a sequence, and it is not good. How can I pass ``dt2 to `type ls = JsonProvider<dt2 >` in order to make it a json again? I can chat, if you are more comfortable.

Comment: You can just use `Array.filter` for the filtering - that will keep the data in an array. (Or, you can use `Array.ofSeq` at the end of the pipeline).