# which library is GetSamples in

Tags: f#, type-providers

Referenced here

[Add calculated key to collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40893531/add-calculated-key-to-collection)

not in FSharp.Data 2.4.6

and no name space referenced in the Answer given by the great TP

GetSample is present.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GetSamples` can be used on your JSON data represented by a `JsonProvider`.
Install the [FSharp.Data](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FSharp.Data/) Nuget package and add the import declaration by using `open FSharp.Data`. Once you have defined a JSON file or some JSON data you should be able to process it further.

```
open FSharp.Data

//type Values = JsonProvider<"yourData.json">
type Values = JsonProvider<""" [{"Name":"Hello"}, {"Name":"World"}] """>
printfn "%A" (Values.GetSamples())
```

Comment: ZiggZagg, Many thanks, I was doing just this, my question relates to the fact that GetSamples() exists when you look through the source code on GitHub (question do we really need to expose people to this level of detail just to use a method sorry function)  But GetSamples() is not present when looking at the object browser (for Fsharp.Data) in visual studio, is the object browser a absolute list of functions ?available?